# Evitar que enlace recargue página boostrap

Tags: li

Muy buenas, tengo un código similar a este, el problema es que a la hora de hacer click sobre la pestaña, hace una regarga, habría alguna forma de evitar esto. Gracias.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si quieres usar jquery, puedes usar la función preventDefault(), te dejo la documentación [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 0):

En mi experiencia, cuando pasa eso es porque olvidé meterle algún JS necesario...

Tendrías que revisar si radica por allí tu inconveniente, porque generalmente ese tipo de inconvenientes no es algo por el que debamos preocuparnos metiendo algunas líneas (porque ya se encargaron aaaaaaaantes de ello...)